# CLI script works. Alias script broke. Corrective action is?

Tags: linux, command-line, script

This CLI (Command Line Interface) script works.
This script is 688 characters with spaces.
This script shows: directories, files, totals in
current directory and
recursive directories (down the file/directory tree).

This script works fine with Ubuntu 20.04.3

```
clear ; ls -1v -w9 -plxhSs --format=single-column --group-directories-first  ; cmd1=` ls -qp | grep -c / ` ; cmd2=`  ls -qp | grep -vc / ` ; cmd3=` ls -1 | wc -l ` ; tput setaf 4 ; pwd | tr '\n' '\000' ; tput sgr0 ; echo "/" ; tput sgr0 ; printf "%9d%s" $cmd1 " dirs" $cmd2 " reg.files" $cmd3 " files current" | tr '\n' ' ' ; tput setaf 13 ; echo "    Ctrl-c Cancel" ; sleep 1 ; cmd4=` find . -type d | wc -l  ` ; cmd5=` find . -type f | wc -l ` ; cmd6=`  find . | wc -l  ` ; tput setaf 13 ; printf "%9d%s" $cmd4 " dirs" $cmd5 " reg.files" $cmd6 " files reclusive" ; echo " " ; tput setaf 13 ; pwd | tr '\n' '\000' ; tput sgr0 ; echo "/" | tr '\n' ' ' ; tput setaf 13 ; echo "+ recursive"
```

Problem is:

1. Above script when moved to alias breaks in terminal session.
2. Above script when moved to alias breaks in ~/.bashrc

Added 9 characters to 688 character script, alias a="
Added 2 characters to 688 character script,  " at the end.

One of 11 errors
bash: alias: dirs 6 : not found

fyi
Why 6 in above error?
There are 6 reg.files in tested dir.

```
alias a="clear ; ls -1v -w9 -plxhSs --format=single-column --group-directories-first  ; cmd1=` ls -qp | grep -c / ` ; cmd2=`  ls -qp | grep -vc / ` ; cmd3=` ls -1 | wc -l ` ; tput setaf 4 ; pwd | tr '\n' '\000' ; tput sgr0 ; echo "/" ; tput sgr0 ; printf "%9d%s" $cmd1 " dirs" $cmd2 " reg.files" $cmd3 " files current" | tr '\n' ' ' ; tput setaf 13 ; echo "    Ctrl-c Cancel" ; sleep 1 ; cmd4=` find . -type d | wc -l  ` ; cmd5=` find . -type f | wc -l ` ; cmd6=`  find . | wc -l  ` ; tput setaf 13 ; printf "%9d%s" $cmd4 " dirs" $cmd5 " reg.files" $cmd6 " files reclusive" ; echo " " ; tput setaf 13 ; pwd | tr '\n' '\000' ; tput sgr0 ; echo "/" | tr '\n' ' ' ; tput setaf 13 ; echo "+ recursive" "
```

Question:
What is the corrective action to get above
CLI script to work as an alias?

--

Comment: Please read [when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed with Kamil: this code contains both single and double quotes. You'll experience quoting hell trying to force it into an alias. Use a function where you can format the commands in a sensible, readable way:

```bsh
a() {
    local cmd1 cmd2 cmd3 cmd4 cmd5 cmd6
    clear 
    ls -1v -w9 -plxhSs --format=single-column --group-directories-first  
    cmd1=$( ls -qp | grep -c / ) 
    cmd2=$(  ls -qp | grep -vc / ) 
    cmd3=$( ls -1 | wc -l ) 
    tput setaf 4 
    pwd | tr '\n' '\000' 
    tput sgr0 
    echo "/" 
    tput sgr0 
    printf "%9d%s" $cmd1 " dirs" $cmd2 " reg.files" $cmd3 " files current" | tr '\n' ' ' 
    tput setaf 13 
    echo "    Ctrl-c Cancel" 
    sleep 1 
    cmd4=$( find . -type d | wc -l  ) 
    cmd5=$( find . -type f | wc -l ) 
    cmd6=$(  find . | wc -l  ) 
    tput setaf 13 
    printf "%9d%s" $cmd4 " dirs" $cmd5 " reg.files" $cmd6 " files reclusive" 
    echo " " 
    tput setaf 13 
    pwd | tr '\n' '\000' 
    tput sgr0 
    echo "/" | tr '\n' ' ' 
    tput setaf 13 
    echo "+ recursive"
}
```